# From data to ArrayList

Tags: java, file, loops, arraylist, set

I am importing a file that has the following:

> 1 2 3 4 5
>
> 4 5 6 7 8
>
> 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
>
> 11 13 15 17 19 21 23
>
> 4 5 5 6 76 7 7 8 8 8 8 8
>
> 23 3 4 3 5 3 53 5 46 46 4 6 5 3 4

I am trying to write a program that will take the first line and add it to `ArrayList<Integer>s1` and the second line into `ArrayList<Integer>s2`. After that, I am calling another method that will use those two (`UID.union(s1,s2)`). However, I am unable to figure out how to add those numbers into the `ArrayList`. I wrote the following, but it doesn't work:

```
ArrayList<Integer> set1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    TreeSet<Integer> s1 = new TreeSet<Integer>();


    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File ("mathsetdata.dat"));

    String str []= input.next().split(" ");

    Set<String> s11 = new TreeSet<String>(Arrays.asList(str));

    for (String k: s11)
    {
        set1.add(Integer.parseInt(k));
    }
```

Also, I am using a loop that will use the first line as `s1`, the second as `s2`, and then call the other class and run it. Then, it will use the third line as `s1` and the fourth as `s2` and run it again.

Comment: What output do you want from the input file?

Comment: The code you wrote will read first input line into set1. What is your question ?  How to do it for multiple lines ? Better post an [MCVE]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you should use `Scanner.nextLine()`method. You use `next()` method will return a single character.
We know that `nextInt()`, `nextLong()`, `nextFloat()` ,`next()` methods are known as **token-reading methods**, because they read tokens separated by delimiters.
Although `next()` and `nextLine()` both read a string,*but `nextLine` is not token-reading method. The `next()` method reads a string delimited by delimiters, and `nextLine()` reads a line ending with a line separator*.
Further speak, if the `nextLine()` mehod is invoked after **token-reading methods**,then this method reads characters that start from this delimiter and end with the line separator. The line separator is read, but it is not part of the string returned by `nextLine()`.

Suppose a text file named `test.txt` contains a line
`34 567`
After the following code is executed,

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("test.txt"));
int intValue = input.nextInt();
String line = input.nextLine();
```

**intValue** contains `34` and line contains the characters *' ', 5, 6, and 7*.

So in your code,you can replace with the following code:

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File ("mathsetdata.dat"));
String str []= input.nextLine().split(" ");
```

Comment: Thanks! but how do I loop through it so that will use the first line as s1, the second as s2, and then call a method and run it. Then, it will use the third line as s1 and the fourth as s2 and run it again? @Edward

Comment: @ZeldaX Maybe you should remove the first line and the second line when you have used this two line.Then run it again,the program will start from the third line.As for how to remove the two line, you can read the remaining lines after read first two lines and then write to the file. Hope it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
    List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>(){};
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File ("mathsetdata.dat"));
    while(input.hasNextLine()){
       String[] strs= input.nextLine().split(" ");//every single line      
       for(String s :strs){
       list.add(Integer.parseInt(s));
    }
```

is it what you want maybe?

Answer (score 0):

You are not reading file in right way also you are adding redundant code. I have added method to convert a line into List of Integers.

```
 private static List<Integer> convertToList(String line) {
        List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (String value : line.split(" ")) {
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(value));
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonSyntaxException, JsonIOException, FileNotFoundException {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("/tmp/mathsetdata.dat"));
        while (input.hasNextLine()) {
            String line = input.nextLine();
            if (line.trim().length() > 0)
                System.out.println(convertToList(line));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are seeking for:

```
public static List<String> readTextFileToCollection(String fileName) throws IOException{

    List<String> allLines = Files.lines(Paths.get(fileName)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    ArrayList<String> finalList = allLines.stream()
        .map(e->{ return new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(e.split(" ")));})
        .reduce(new ArrayList<String>(), (s1,s2) -> UID.union(s1,s2));

    return finalList;
}
```

In order to work this solution; your `UID.union(s1,s2)` *should return the merged arraylist.* That means, you should be able to write something like below without compilation errors:

```
ArrayList<String> mergedList = UID.union(s1,s2);
```